# C difference between using if or while in recursion

Tags: c, if-statement, recursion, while-loop

While trying to find different possibilities of writing a recursive factorial function, I noticed that I got confused about the differences of using `while` or `if` in the following recursive function. I watched the steps for each option using the `gdb debugger`, and couldn't see any difference either. I know the functionality of the `while loop`, and that it works iteratively. But since its body contains a recursive call of the function as a return statement, the current function should be 'left' and a new one should be entered, which will lead to entering a new while loop? It seems to me that in this case it works like a regular `if statement`? I appreciate any clarification on this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int recursion(int n)
{
    while(n > 0)
        return n * recursion(n-1);
    return 1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int n = 5;

    printf("%d\n", recursion(n));       

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

alternative recursive function using `if` leading to the same result:

```
int recursion(int n)
{
    if(n > 0)
        return n * recursion(n-1);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This is an endless loop. It is the same difference as always between `whille` (loop) and `if` (conditional statement).

Comment: so why does my compiler run it smoothly and return 120 in this case?

Comment: @Olaf That may not be an endless loop but yes number of iterations would be many more than normal for a large input.

Comment: Number of iterations for this case is exactly the same cause the `return` statement as Fabian said in his answer

Comment: @Mr.E Huh , my bad  , thought something else .

Comment: @ameyCU: Sorry, I missed the `return` inside the loop. I hate recursion. Hmm, yes, it really should behave the same, but the `while` is nonsense. What does OP want to accomplish? Just to ask a question?

Comment: I stand corrected by @ameyCU. Just note that your compiler does not run anything! It just translates your source code. It is the CPU which runs all software.

Comment: FYI: Tail-recursion might be faster and possibly avoid stack nesting.

Comment: The ideal solution is to remove the recursion entirely and just use a loop. One particularly good way to show off that you are a skilled C programmer is to write programs that are 100% free of recursion.

Comment: @Olaf Question would be avoided as OP debugs the program , and  he must have got his answer by debugger :-).

Comment: @Olaf I want to accomplish that I understand what's happening and why, considering whether it was just a special case/luck/or the like. And not just keep guessing why the code did what I wanted it to do, and moving on to the next chapter, ignoring my confusion =)

Comment: @reinka: You can use an axe to peel an apple. But it is likely not an appropriate tool for that. Same for constructs. There is a reason every programming language has loop constructs and conditional constructs. No use in abusing `while` as a conditional statement. If you have not understood the difference, **this** is the wrong way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is technically the same in this case because as soon as you enter the while loop you quit it with the `return` statement. The following two statements are also the same:

```
while (a) {
  b;
  break;
}
```

and

```
if (a) {
  b;
}
```

But you shouldn't use `while` in this case because it's intended for loops, so there should be execution paths where it executes multiple times. There's a reason that there are both `if` and `while`.

Comment: While they **behave** identical, they are still not the same, as the `while` might generate different code (depends on the compiler).